# Web scraping in R: issue with pattern &nbsp, unable to get desired output

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am trying to pull in the table data available from a website using R. There is only one table present on website.

Below is my code which I am trying to use to extract table data.

```
thepage = readLines('Link')
data4 <- gsub("&nbsp;", "",thepage)
mypattern ='<td class="first">([^<]*)</td>'
datalines = grep(mypattern,data4[67:length(data4)],value=TRUE)
datalines
```

However the above mentioned code is unable to match pattern against the below mentioned html code.

Any suggestions on how to set the pattern to get desired output.

HTML:

```
<td class="first">
     &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  &nbsp;AAAF
</td>
```

Desired Output: AAAF

Comment: What's with the `67:`? Should that be a different number in this example? The `grep` doesn't look across elements in a string vector. It looks like you have your start tag in a different string than the end tag in the vector. If you want to use `grep`, the pattern you want to match needs to be in the same string (and by default the same line in that same string -- otherwise you need to enable multiline regular expressions). But really parsing HTML/XML with regular expressions is a terrible idea. Use something like `xml2` to parse a structured document and extract with xpath.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I used grep with 67 to start matching lines from 67 from where the table code starts in HTML; point at the table. Also, xml2 gives me connection error 401.